# Haskell - Tree traversal: preorder

Tags: haskell, types, tree, preorder

I am fairly new to Haskell, and is trying to work on an assignment from my class.
I am trying to create a preorder function to traverse through a tree object in the following format

```
preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
preorder f g Empty = []
preorder f g (Leaf x) = [x]
```

My Tree class is as following

```
data Tree a b = Empty | Leaf b | Branch a (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
```

When defining the preorder function, I get errors as shown below.

```
Couldn't match expected type 'c' with actual type 'b'
'c' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c].
'b' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c].
```

And they occurred at the last preorder function definition

```
preorder f g (Leaf x) = [x]
```

Comment: Hint: you haven't used your `f` or `g` parameters at all.

Comment: Yea I noticed that, but I don't know why I even need those two functions there. I don't know what are supposed to be plugged in. On the assignment sheet our instructor assigned the function declaration `preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]`
and said that we will have 2 functions as input to the preorder function.

Comment: Consider the the `preorder` definition for `Leaf`: the type of `x` is `b` (which you can see from your data type). However, `preorder` should return a list of elements of type `c`. If only you had a way to convert something from type `b` to type `c`...

Comment: yea I understand that, and the reason that we need to convert them to a new type `c` is because there might be different types of elements in the tree. However, I really don't know how to do that or even where to start with...

Comment: The error message tells you that value of type `c` is expected where you provided a value of type `b`. Clearly, since you are constructing a list of elements of type `c`, it tells you `[x]` is wrong. Need somehow to get `[value of type c here produced from value of type b]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `Tree a b` contains leaves with elements of type `b` and branches with elements of type `a` in addition to empty leaves. You wish to visit each node of the tree in preorder, collecting the *results* of applying the functions `f :: a -> c` and `g :: b -> c` in a list of type `[c]`. The reason that the compiler complains about your `preorder` function is that `x` has type `b`; this forces `c` to unify with `b`. But this is a less general type than you have indicated to the compiler. As an exercise, see if you can write a more specific type for your function that the compiler accepts. Hint: are `b` and `c` distinct types?

However, you are given a function `g :: b -> c`. Applying this function to `x` yields a value of type `c`, and *this* value can be collected into a list of type `[c]`. This list may *or may not* contain elements of type `a` or `b`. You can rewrite the preorder traversal in accord with the given signature in the following way:

```
preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
preorder f g Empty          = []
preorder f g (Leaf b)       = [g b]
preorder f g (Branch a l r) = f a : preorder f g l ++ preorder f g r
```